# Using conditions in Graphical modeler QGIS 3.10.5

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-modeler, if-else

I have a question about my model which is quite complex.

I have two types of line INPUT and the model will not be executed unless one of the line INPUT is empty. The problem is with a tool '`Snap points to lines`' (logically - because there are no lines and points neither).

The question is, if there is some way with Graphical modeler to use a condition like

```
IF one of the line INPUT is empty 
THEN 'freeze' this branch of model, but continue with the second line INPUT
```

I guess the best way is to turn the model into a script and here I can manage better the conditions.
But I am not really PRO in Python so anybody can give me a hand?

[image: model]

Comment: Can you share some insight on why you use the tool, if there's no input for it?

Comment: In graphical modeler, no, I once made a feature request for this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34804 so maybe some day...

Comment: @Erik - Ok the model is for pre-processing some data for electric infrastructure. In general there are 2 types of cables - underground and aérial.
So the model prepare the data for processing over certain areas - but it works just for the areas where the two types of cables ( aérial and underground) are present.
If not the model will give an error that one of the type of cable is empty.
My aime is to make this model  working even for the cases where only one type of cable is present.

Comment: @MrXsquared ok thank you

Comment: You could run the model separately for both layers, if both are present, or you could merge the layers before running (which then later might require some select by expression)?

Answer (score 6):

There is a new feature if you use QGIS 3.14 or higher - see visual changelog: [New modeler algorithm for creating conditional branches](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-new-modeler-algorithm-for-creating-conditional-branches):

> A key feature introduced in QGIS 3.14 was the ability for models to
> have a conditional branch.

See here for [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/modelertools.html#conditional-branch) and here [for details](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/advanced-qgis.html#using-conditions-in-modeler).

So you should think about updating your QGIS version to the current QGIS 3.16, as this will also be the new Long Term Release.

For older versions, think if you could not add a QGIS expression to define inputs in such a was as to achieve what you want.