# Make modeler stop / raise exception when field doesn't exist

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a model which use Field calculator:

```
case 
    when "A_FIELDNAME_THAT_DOESNT_EXIST"<=50 then 1 
    else 0
end
```

The field doesn't exist, the output is 0 but the model keep executing which is very bad. Is there a way to make it stop to alert me something went wrong?

There is the model tool "Raise exception", but I cant figure out a way of checking if the field exist.

When executing Field Calculator manually it will not run when the field doesnt exists, which is what I want I modeler:

[image]

With the help from the answer this is working, making the model stop:

```
not map_exist(attributes(),'A_FIELDNAME_THAT_DOESNT_EXIST')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this expression to check if a fieldname exists:

```
map_exist (attributes(),'A_FIELDNAME_THAT_DOESNT_EXIST') -> false

map_exist (attributes(),'A_FIELDNAME_THAT_EXISTS') -> true
```

Use it together with a [conditional branch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383419/88814) based on this output.