# Conditional branch and input

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm building a script in the graphical modeler. I have different inputs that I have to give and one is optional.
I'm trying to build a `conditional branch` that check the presence or absence of the optional input. But I can't find an expression for that.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383404/using-conditions-in-graphical-modeler-qgis-3-10-5

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Comment: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-new-modeler-algorithm-for-creating-conditional-branches

Comment: Yes, I use `conditional branch`. But my question is what expression I can use to test if my layer `input2`, which is optional, is given in the model? For exemple, in the `conditional branch`, the expression would be `layer_exist(@input2)`. But the expression `layer_exist` doesn't exist... So is it a way to do that?

Comment: i think there is something broken or i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 3):

I found myself. It's simple as I thought.
I just use a conditional branch with `@input2 IS NOT NULL`, and the other one with `@input2 IS NULL`.

Comment: nice i was about to update with the same. this https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39119 pointed me to the same solution

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure something is broken (btw QGIS 3.16.11)

I have a model with:

- a Vector Layer input named 'test'
- a print warning using the following expression `if(parameter('test'), 'TRUE', 'FALSE')`
- a conditional branch with:

  - **true_branch** with expression `if(parameter('test'), True, False)`
  - **false_branch** with expression `if(parameter('test'), False, True)`

When I run the model twice (once without layer passed to it and once with) I get the following where the warning is working fine but the conditional branch fails
[image]

Comment: I don’t understand your true_branch and false_branche? In evercase, the value will be true and false (case you add the layer) or false and true (case you don’t add the layer! So it will always trigger both branches? Or I ‘m wrong?

Comment: Plus, you write if(parameter(test), true, false)… but if parameter(test) is what? Not NULL?

Comment: parameter('test') return the value inside the 'input parameters' dictionnary you can see on the picture. 
The conditions are simple if parameter('test') == True than the true branch should be active and the other one inactive and the opposite when parameter('test') == False, basically I was trying to make a if else with the conditional branch system